# Looping over a bitmask

Tags: algorithm, bitmask

This is a submission to the [TopCoder SRM 466 "Lottery Ticket" problem](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=10860). I've seen this pattern used multiple times for this problem.

> Nick likes to play the lottery. The cost of a single lottery ticket is price. Nick has exactly four banknotes with values `b1`, `b2`, `b3` and `b4` (some of the values may be equal). He wants to know if it's possible to buy a single lottery ticket without getting any change back. In other words, he wants to pay the exact price of a ticket using any subset of his banknotes. Return "POSSIBLE" if it is possible or "IMPOSSIBLE" if it is not (all quotes for clarity).

```
string buy(int p, int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4) {
    int arr[] = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
    for (int msk = 0; msk < (1 << 4); ++msk) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            if (msk & (1 << i)) {
                sum += arr[i];
            }
        }
        if (sum == p) return "POSSIBLE";
    }
    return "IMPOSSIBLE";
}
```

Can someone explain how this works? I don't understand why he puts the values into an array and loops using two nested for loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be extended to any number of bank notes but lets go over this example.

The idea with this solution is to use brute-force approach to solve the problem. That means I will try all possible solutions and if one of them is working then the result is positive.

Working solution in this case means the sum of the bank notes that I've picked is equal to the `p`.

Lets look at this piece of code first:

```
for (int msk = 0; msk < (1 << 4); ++msk)
```

This says I'm going to iterate over all numbers from `0` to `2^4-1`, i.e. `0-15`.

If you write these numbers in their binary notation, you will notice that they cover all possible combinations of length 4 (we don't have to write all leading zeroes, but it would actually have 32 bits in total for type `int`).

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Lets pick one of the examples, e.g. `1010`. This means that I will pick numbers at positions `1` and `3` (0-based looking from right to the left). Then I'll check if the sum of these two numbers is equal to `p`.

The next for-loop sums all the numbers at positions that have `1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    if (msk & (1 << i)) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
}
```

If we break it down, then we have the `msk` which represents the current combination we are checking and `(1 << i)` which is just shift-left bitwise operation that gives us `2^i`, or in binary notation:

```
0001 = 1 << 0
0010 = 1 << 1
0100 = 1 << 2
1000 = 1 << 3
```

NOTE: `(1 << i)` is inside the parenthesis because `&` has higher priority and we don't want that in this case.

If you use `&` operator between two integers, you will get the bitwise operation, e.g.

```
1010 & 1000 = 1000   // this is greater than 0
1010 & 0100 = 0000   // this is equal to 0
```

Therefore `if (msk & (1 << i))` will only be true for positions that have `1` in the current combination, i.e. `msk`.

I hope this also explains the reason why he puts the values inside the array - it's because he wants to assign each bank note an index and then use that note if the mask has `1` for its position, instead of figuring out which of the 4 variables should be used.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. I am now fully confident I understand it. Another answerer told me this is an exponential algorithm. Do you know any more efficient way to do this given possibly thousands of values?

Comment: Indeed. This has exponential complexity because you are trying all possibilities and there are 2^n in total. The actual complexity would be O(2^n * n), where n is the number of bank notes.

This can be solved in a better way using dynamic programming. It's a sub-problem of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. In this case the value (cost) of each item would be 1 and you are only interested in weights.

Take a look at the knapsack algorithm first and if you don't understand how to solve it then I could explain it in more details.
The complexity is still not very good O(P*N)

Comment: Fantastic explanation! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It just generates all 16 possible combinations. Every combination is represented by 4 bits, 1 meaning the banknote is used, 0 meaning it is not used.

Then it calculates the sum of the combinations and if the sum is correct, it prints "possible".

Answer (score 1):

For each currency note, you have two choices, take it or leave it (on or off). 
With 4 notes, you can see them as 4 bits, and you go through all possible combinations of picking them if you go through 0000 to 1111 in binary.

That's what the bitvector does. The outer loop generates all possible subsets and the inner loop evaluates a subset to see if it matches the required sum.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what the time complexity of this algorithm is?

Comment: It is an exponential algorithm in terms of number of currency notes. O(2^n) where n is number of notes, 4 in this case.